# Abrir un archivo de Excel desde un form de ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel

Hola amigos estoy recibiendo un excel como **HttpRequestPostedFileBase** desde un **form** de **Asp.NET**, pero necesito abrirlo, se que puedo almacenar el archivo y mandarle a mi

> Workbook sheet = excel.Workbooks.Open("ruta/file.xls");

La ruta del archivo para que lo abra, pero en este caso quiero abrirlo y confirmar su contenido previo a guardarlo. Entonces quiero abrirlo, hasta ahora tengo esto, pero me pide el nombre con la ruta, alguien sabe si puedo abrirlo de esta misma forma o alguna otra librería?

```js
if (Request.Files.Count > 0) {
  var file = Request.Files[0];
  string value = Request.Form["lstlistaCuentas"].ToString();
  string[] keys = Request.Form.AllKeys;
  string cuenta = form["lstlistaCuentas"].ToString();
  string banco = form["lstBancos"].ToString();

  string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
  string fname = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

  if (extension == ".xls" || extension == ".xlsx") {
    switch (banco) {
      //banamex
      case ("1"):
        string fn = file.FileName;
        if (!fn.Contains("BX")) {
          return View("Error");
        } else {
          Application excel = new Application();

          Workbook sheet = excel.Workbooks.Open(" quiero mandar unicamente el HttpRequestPostedFileBase ");
          Worksheet x = excel.ActiveSheet as Worksheet;
          _Worksheet xlWorksheet = sheet.Sheets[1];
          Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
        }


        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es abrir un fichero Excel directamente desde la variable `HttpRequestPostedFileBase` para validar el documento y posteriormente guardarlo en disco.

Según [este comentario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4349549/2144342) en la comunidad inglesa, con la librería [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
public void ImportExcelXls(HttpPostedFileBase fileBase)
{
    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fileBase.InputStream))
    {
        // get the first worksheet in the workbook
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
        int col = 1;

        for (int row = 1; worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value != null; row++)
        {
            // do something with worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value                    
        }
    } // the using 
}
```